# Strange effect with Scrolltop on Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, scrolltop

When i'm on Chrome or Safari, and i click the second button (.scroll2), it make like a reload to the top fast effect and then goes where it supposed to. Any way to stop this effect ?

```
$(".scroll").click(function() {
   $("body").animate({scrollTop:$('#bloc-2').position().top} , 4000);
});

$(".scroll2").click(function() {
   $("body").animate({scrollTop: $('#bloc-3').position().top }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: replicate issue on jsfiddle, if you can

Comment: I cant really, but when i click my scroll2, u can see the page going 1 sec to the top of the website and then going back where my .scroll2 button are and continue the scroll where it have to go.

Comment: i guess you are clicking on anchor links `<a>`, right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following my guess, if you are clicking on anchor links with href attribute (e.g `href="#"`), you should prevent default behaviour:

```
$(".scroll").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("body").animate({scrollTop:$('#bloc-2').position().top} , 4000);
});

$(".scroll2").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("body").animate({scrollTop: $('#bloc-3').position().top }, 5000);
});
```